# How to communicate from Child to Parent page using EventEmitters

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am new for Angular and i am now developing ionic apps using angular,My requirement is communicate from child to parent page using Event Emitters(Just want to change Parent page title from child page my code is below please suggest me how can i do this),I don't even idea about this concept can some one help me please

## parent.html:-

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <button menuToggle left>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
</ion-content>
```

### parnet.ts:

```
export class Parent{
  title:string;
  getNotification(evt) {
    this.title = ""+evt;
   }
}
```

### child.html:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <h2>Grocery Page</h2>
    <button ion-button (click)="sendNotification()" color="secondary" full>Notify my parent!</button>
</ion-content>
```

### child.ts:

```
export class Child{

  @Output() notifyParent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  sendNotification() {
    this.notifyParent.emit('Parent Page');
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the child element name

Comment: i updated my code please check now

Comment: still not posting the child component selector

Comment: i updated please check now

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of your child component is correct, now you just need to listen for `notifyParent` event in parent and change the value to received one, like this:

```
<child-component (notifyParent)="getNotification($event)"></child-component>
```

And here is a simple [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzhukg?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

On your parent component's template you can set an event emitter to your child as follows,

```
<child (notifyParent) = "getNotification($event)"></child>
```

ChildComponent :

```
export class Child{

   @Output() notifyParent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

   sendNotification() {
     this.notifyParent.emit('Parent Page');
   }
}
```

Parent Component:

```
export class Parent{
  title:string;
  getNotification(evt) {
     this.title = evt;
  }
}
```

Comment: if i do like this child page UI is appear in my parent page UI

Comment: I just want to change Parent page Action bar title from child page

Comment: The whole concept of a child component is that. To be inside a parent component UI. If you just want to change the title from else where use a service for that.

Comment: oh is it no possible using EventEmiters?

Comment: Where is your child page isn't it inside your parent?

Comment: Child page is one of the tabbar page in parent page